# I need help in designing an analog front end for a MOSFET based sensor

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, analog

I'm currently designing an analog front end for an ion sensor (ISFET), the purpose of which is to **automatically extend the sensing** range of the sensor once the analyte concentration reaches the detection limit of the sensor/ **return to the normal sensing range** of the sensor once the analyte concentration is within the sensor's normal sensing range. Here is a sample circuit of the MOSFET based sensor which can only sense within its default range limit (output is between the capacitor C1 and ground) :
[image]

I've already figured out how to extend the sensor's sensing range (by placing a non-inverting amplifier between the source and gate terminals) as shown in the image:
[image]

My current roadblock is how to **automate** the process. For now, I just manually switch between the default and the extended range using the following circuit:

[image]

The voltage output for the normal concentration ranges from 0.88-1.0v, while the voltage output for the lower concentration, amplified by the non-inverting amplifier, ranges from 0.465-0.505V. The voltage ranges are specific for a certain type of ion (Cu+2)

I already had two ideas in mind on how to execute this automation: My first idea involves varying the resistance of either the feedback or input resistor of the non-inverting amplifier (changing the gain multiplier to "1" during normal concentrations and "2" during low concentrations), though I currently have no idea how to execute that. My second idea (actually suggested by someone) is to make use of the switching circuit mentioned before and add a couple of comparators and flip flops, but I am also having a hard time on how to execute it.

Comment: Try putting an analog switch in series with R9; sense the actual voltage with a comparator (with some hysteresis would be my take) and if it is in the normal range, disable the switch (makes U5 a follower) otherwise enable it (amplifier has gain).You would need a bit of logic - if gain is true and range appears normal leave the gain in place.

Comment: Or just sense the range digitally and then switch the gain

Comment: @PeterSmith by analog switch, perhaps you were referring to a bilateral switch? I might try that, thanks for the suggestion!